# How to plot points using Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a numpy array `precip_subset` that has a shape of `(31, 60, 48)`. `precip_subset` was created by merging 31 datasets; the first variable in the dataset represents the day, the 2nd is a representation of longitude, and the 3rd is a representation of latitude. There is a unique value for precipitation at each position in the dataset; for example, `print(precip_subset[1,0,32])` will give me a value of `1.05`.

I'll show what I have done so far with my code:

```
data_low = precip_subset[(precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.14062)]
anomalies = []
for val in data_low:
    if val < 1: 
        anomalies.append(val)
        print(anomalies)

data_low_indices1 = np.where((precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 1))
data_low_indices2 = np.array(np.where((precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 1))).T
anomalies_ind = []
for ind in data_low_indices2:
    anomalies_ind.append(ind)
    print(np.asarray(anomalies_ind))
```

Basically, with this code I am able to get the values of precipitation and their indices in the original dataset, `precip_subset`. From here, I would like to plot this data with Basemap -- I would like to have a point on the map where an anomaly is found. `precip_subset` was created like so:

```
data_path = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT\3B42RT_Daily.201001.7.nc4"
f = Dataset(data_path)

latbounds = [ -31 , -19 ]  
lonbounds = [ 131, 146 ] 
lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

precip_subset = f.variables['precipitation'][ : , lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]
```

And this is what I have done so far to plot the data using Basemap:

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=131.,llcrnrlat=-31,urcrnrlon=146.,urcrnrlat=-19.)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 45.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
m.imshow(anomalies_ind)
plt.show()
```

However, the image I get is not what I would like (see image below).

[image]

Does anyone know how I can plot `anomalies_ind` using Basemap, with a point where each anomaly is found?

Comment: why can no one answer this

Comment: you haven't included any data. A small sample of `anomalies_ind` with few lines is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`imshow` just plots the data you give it as an image, overriding anything else. So is definitely not what you want. Since you haven't given any indication of the shape of `anomalies_ind`, I have put an example here. All you need to do is map the lats and lons to x/y pixel coordinates, and plot them. the `'o'` parameter to `plot` just says to plot circles, rather than lines.

```
anomalies_ind = [(-29.027008, 135.547227),
                 (-22.774524, 137.824754)]

lats = np.array(anomalies_ind)[:, 0]
lons = np.array(anomalies_ind)[:, 1]


m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=131.,llcrnrlat=-31,urcrnrlon=146.,urcrnrlat=-19.)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 45.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
#m.imshow(anomalies_ind)

x, y = m(lons, lats)
m.plot(x, y, 'o')

plt.show()
```